# django 1.2.1: Override model name in admin interface?

Tags: python, django

I have a model called "Activity" in my django app. in the admin interface, it appears on the screen as "Activitys". how can I override the label on the admin page to make it "Activities" instead?

I see in the archives how to do this for a field, but not for a model itself. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

    # your fields....

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Activity'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Activities'
```